# Using an array of template function pointers

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I have the following code for convolution types and various image data types.

```
typedef PF_Err(*funcptrFn) (void* refcon, A_long thread_indexL, A_long i, A_long iterationsL);

template <typename InFormat> funcptrFn ConvolutionType[]{
    Convolve_Prewitt, Convolve_Sobel,
    Convolve_Robinson, Convolve_Kirsch,
    Convolve_Laplacian, NULL
};
```

```cpp
static PF_Err Convolve_Prewitt(void* data, A_long threadID, A_long i, A_long iter)
{
    InFormat* ptr = (InFormat*)((char*)data + sizeof(InFormat) * iter);
    for (int x = 0; x < max_cols; x++) {
        ptr++ = Prewitt_Ops(ptr); // Red
        ptr++ = Prewitt_Ops(ptr); // Green
        ptr++ = Prewitt_Ops(ptr); // Blue
        ptr++; // Alpha - Do Nothing
    }
}
```

InFormat can be char, short or float. I want to pass InFormat to the function pointers so I know the type of input array. The function names indicate the type of Edge Detection convolution.
How should I do this ?

Here is the solution.

```
typedef PF_Err(*refConFn) (void* refcon, A_long thread_indexL, A_long i, A_long iterationsL);

template <typename InFormat, int type> PF_Err Convolve(void* refcon, A_long thread_indexL, A_long i, A_long iterationsL) {
switch type {
case X: return ConvolutionTypeX<InFormat>(refcon, indexL,i,iterationsL);
}
}
```

EDIT:- Answer is in the comments - Almost every switch type should be a virtual function, and the rest should be std::visit over std::variant

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is desired functionality. Note that use of function pointers in C++ is considered outdated approach.

Comment: There is no such thing as "template function pointer" (or "template function" for that matter). A *function template* is a recipe for baking functions. It is not a function. There are no pointers to function templates. A function template does not have a type. A specialisation of a function template is just a function, without any "template" in it. Its type is a normal function type. You can have an array of function pointers, including pointers to function template specialisations, but they must all be of the same type, like elements of any array.

Comment: I need a single function that will call various convolution types and pass the type of image data via typename InFormat. I can do this via a switch statement but I think using templates or function pointers is a cleaner solution.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show code (or pseudocode, not necessarily working C++ code) which does something, and then maybe we can find a (better) way of doing that. It is not clear what you mean by "pass the type of image data". C++ types are not objects and cannot be passed to functions. A line of code is better than a paragraph describing it.

Comment: I have edited the question to show code as requested.

Comment: Man all this is matrix manipulations, so make this class readable matrix operations. You do not need function of pointers. Those Prewitt, Sobel, Robinson, Kirschare, Laplacian are just different matrix. So you do not need templates or pointers to functions.

Comment: I need to have different operations based on whether Prewitt, Sobel, Robinson, Kirschare, Laplacian are chosen. Also, the image data type needs to be passed. How would this be done without using a switch statement ?

Comment: I updated the question with the answer - I used a combo of function pointers and templates.

Comment: Almost every `switch type` should be a virtual function, and the rest should be `std::visit` over `std::variant`.

Comment: std::variant is C++17 only though. I'll read up some examples and see if I can improve the answer.